# AjaxDoc - how to configure?

Tags: javascript, documentation, sandcastle, shfb

i want to document my project. Everything is working fine, but i cant get AjaxDoc working.

Please, could somebody write me some short tutorial how to use them?

I have SHFB integrated in Visual studio.
Then i downloaded the WebApp project from http://ajaxdoc.codeplex.com/ and added them as Existing Web Site to my solution. I have built this site, and his URL wrote to AjaxDoc plugin.

Now, the AjaxDoc is defaultly configured to get comments from MicrosoftAjax.js and it works for me.
But i tried to add my own MyJavaScript.js and create MyJavaScript.project.xml in Projects folder but it doesn't work.

JScript.project.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<project xmlns:scriptdoc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  scriptdoc:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ScriptDocProject.xsd">
  <scripts>
    <script path="projects/JScript.js"/>
  </scripts>
  <namespaces>
    <namespace>TestScript</namespace>
  </namespaces>
</project>
```

JScript.js:

```
    /// <reference path="_references.js" />

    Type.registerNamespace("TestScript");

    TestScript.JavaScriptClass = function demoScript$JavaScriptClass() {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is a summary for the singleton
        /// </summary>

        /// <field name="field1" type="String" >This is a demo field.</field>

        this._property1Value = 1;
    }

    TestScript.JavaScriptClass.prototype = {
        method: function (param1, param2) {
            /// <summary>
            /// This is a demo method of <see cref="JavaScriptClass" />.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="param1" type="Number" integer="true">This is parameter 1 of the demo method <see cref="JavaScriptClass.method" />.</param>
            /// <param name="param2" type="String">This is parameter 2 of the demo method <see cref="JavaScriptClass.method" />.</param>
            /// <returns type="String">Returns a demo result.<returns>
            return "Hello world";
        },
        get_Property1: function () {
            /// <value type="Number" integer="true">This is a demo property.</value>
            return this._property1Value;
        },
        set_Property1: function (value) {
            this._property1Value;
        },
        field1: null
    };

    demoScript.JavaScriptClass.registerClass("TestScript.JavaScriptClass");
```

I copy this from some project found on internet...

What i am doing wrong? And how could i comment my own project, not only scripts in AjaxDoc/Projects folder?

Thanks for replies.